# HTTP 3 - How to resolve this error

Tags: ssl, haproxy, make, http3

```
user@host:~/haproxy-2.7.1$ make TARGET=linux2.6.32 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_NGHTTP2=1 USE_QUIC=1
  CC      src/slz.o
  CC      src/ev_poll.o
  CC      src/ssl_sock.o
In file included from include/haproxy/quic_cc.h:33,
                 from include/haproxy/quic_conn.h:41,
                 from src/ssl_sock.c:68:
include/haproxy/quic_conn-t.h:540:30: error: field ‘level’ has incomplete type
  540 |  enum ssl_encryption_level_t level;
      |                              ^~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
make: *** [Makefile:969: src/ssl_sock.o] Error 1
```

Comment: programming question should be asked on stackoverflow